Reactive Spring MessageSource
I am working on a WebFlux application with Reactor. I have an implementation of Spring MessageSource that in order to get an internationalized message, it calls to a database where the messages are stored. The problem is I need one http header from the incoming http request in order to get this message from the database because is a parameter I need to get this message. That header is set in the Context of Reactor in a WebFilter but the problem is I cannot access that Reactor Context in the implementation of the MessageSource with Mono.deferContextual. How to do this?
I attach below the code. Where I have the problem is in the class AbstractMessageSource where I do a http request and inside that class there is no way to do Mono.deferContextual.... because I have to block in order to get the context but then I would get a new Context because block is creating a new inner Subscription that is not part of the outer Reactor pipeline.
This is the AbstractMessageSource:
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Component
    public class RemoteAbstractMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource {     

        @Override
        public String resolveCode(String code, Locale locale) {
           
    
           if (StringUtils.containsWhitespace(code)) {
                return code;
            }           
            

            var headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setAcceptLanguageAsLocales(List.of(locale));

            var entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

            try {
                return restTemplate.exchange(UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/public/v1/messages/i18n/{code}")
                        .queryParams(queryParams).build(code).toString(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
            } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
                throw CustomErrorException.of(e);
            }
        }
    }


Thanks


Could you show some code?

I edited the question with attached code

I mean related code (and just it). It's unclear how you put the data into context, and where you want to access it

I simplified the code. The problem is that before making the request using RestTemplate, I would need to access the Context where I put some values from WebFilter. This AbstractMessageSource is a Spring component I register in Spring context to resolve messages. This AbstractMessageSource is called automatically by Spring if you register any Spring Validator and add some error messages to return.

You cannot access the Context from a non-reactive code, but you can copy those values from the context before calling the non-reactive code. Do you have a reactive code that calls this function?

I understand  what you say, I could create a method parameter to inject the value from the Context, the problem is what I commented about Spring Validators and the BindingResult that is automatically called by Spring, not by me

Where those service get their values usually? How it works in a non-reactive application?

In a non reactive application, those values are got from ThreadLocal. As I said, this RemoteAbstractMessageSource is called by Spring automatically for example when you implement some Spring Validators and you put the @Valid annotation in any method of a Controller

I guess I understand the problem now. I initially thought it's in your code. But it seems to be about Spring WebFlux configuration and how it handles locales/message source. Unfortunately I don't know the answer.
